# Proxy requests using Apache transparently

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

I am using Apache to forward an URL to another URL using mod_proxy transparently.

To illustrate what I am doing, this is my Apache configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myurl.mysite.com

    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPass / http://www.whatismyip.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://www.whatismyip.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

I am using "whatismyip.com" site, because it seems to detect proxies, so it is a good one to test. *SSLProxyEngine* is enabled because my destination site uses SSL (the one in *ProxyPass* directive).

With this simple configuration, most things works fine. But I do not want the destination site to detect that it is being accessed through a proxy. The destination site should "think" it is being direct accessed by the Apache server (the proxy) and only by it.

Why? For some reason I don't know, I can access the end point site, but can not login when I'm using the proxy. The end point runs legacy software, so changes on it are not an option.

I suppose the end point is doing some check, or maybe it is using some parameter that is leading to this (direct access lead to no problems). My solution is to make some kind of transparent access.